# Determine whether $f(x, y) = \frac{1}{x(xy)^{1/2}}$ is integrable over some open sets

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

I am studying analysis, using Munkres' book "Analysis on Manifolds". I am in the chapter about improper integrals and I want to solve the following question:

> Let $f(x, y) =  \frac{1}{x(xy)^{1/2}}$ for $x > 0$ and $y > 0$. Let:
> \begin{align} 
> A_0 &= \{(x, y) \ | \ 0 < x < 1 \text{ and } x < y < 2x \} \\
> B_0 &= \{(x, y) \ | \ 0 < x < 1 \text{ and } x^2 < y < 2x^2 \} 
>    \end{align}
> Determine whether $\int_{A_0} f$ and $\int_{B_0} f$ exist; if so, calculate.

My idea is to use Theorem 15.2:

> **Theorem 15.2** Let $A$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Choose a sequence $C_n$ of compact rectfiable subsets of $A$ whose union is $A$ such that $C_N \subset Int \ C_{N+1}$ for each $N$. Then $f$ is integrable over $A$ if and only if the sequence $\int_{C_N} |f|$ is bounded. In this case, $\int_{A} f = \lim_{N \to \infty} \int_{C_N} |f|$.

I plan to choose $C_N = \{(x, y) \ | \ \frac{1}{n} \leq x \leq 1 - \frac{1}{n} \text{ and } x  \leq y \leq 2x \}$ for $A_0$.

I plan to choose $C_N = \{(x, y) \ | \ \frac{1}{n} \leq x \leq 1 - \frac{1}{n} \text{ and } x^2  \leq y \leq 2x^2 \}$ for $B_0$.

Is this the right way to proceed? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does "exist" mean? Everything is positive and continuous, so the integral exists in $(0,\infty].$

Comment: Yes, I agree that the integral exists in $(0, \infty]$. I think Munkres' definition of "exist" is a bit different than that. In Munkres': "Let $A$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R^n}$; let $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. If $f$ is non-negative in $A$, we define the (extended) integral of $f$ over $A$, denoted as $\int_{A}f$, to be the supremum of the numbers $\int_{D}f$, as $D$ ranges over all compact rectifiable subsets of $A$, provided this supremum exists".

Comment: So I think that, for Munkres, if an integral would be equal to $\infty$ he considers that the integral does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. First, notice that in both cases we have $f$ = $|f|$.

For $A_0$ you will obtain that $\int_{A_0} f$ does not exist:

> Note that:
> $$ \int_{C_N} |f| = \int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{1 - \frac{1}{n}} \int_{x}^{2x} \frac{1}{x \sqrt{xy}} dy \ dx =  \int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{1 - \frac{1}{n}} \frac{1}{x \sqrt{x}} \ (2 \sqrt{y})|_{x}^{2x} = \int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{1 - \frac{1}{n}} \frac{1}{x \sqrt{x}} \ 2 \sqrt{x} (\sqrt{2} - 1) = \\ 2 (\sqrt{2} - 1) \int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{1 - \frac{1}{n}} \frac{1}{x} = 2 (\sqrt{2} - 1) \ [\ln(1 - \frac{1}{n}) - \ln(1/n)].$$
> Since $\lim_{N \to \infty} \ln(1 - 1/n) = 1$ and $\lim_{N \to \infty} \ln(1/n) = - \infty$, the sequence $\int_{C_N} |f|$ is not bounded and therefore $\int_{A_0} f$ does not exist.

For $B_0$ you will obtain that $\int_{B_0} f$ does exist and it's value is: $4(\sqrt{2} - 1)$.

> Note that:
> $$ \int_{C_N} |f| = \int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{1 - \frac{1}{n}} \int_{x^2}^{2x^2} \frac{1}{x \sqrt{xy}} dy \ dx =  \int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{1 - \frac{1}{n}} \frac{1}{x \sqrt{x}} \ (2 \sqrt{y})|_{x^2}^{2x^2} = \int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{1 - \frac{1}{n}} \frac{1}{x \sqrt{x}} \ 2 x (\sqrt{2} - 1) = \\ 2 (\sqrt{2} - 1) \int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{1 - \frac{1}{n}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} = 4 (\sqrt{2} - 1) \ [\sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{n}} - \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}].$$
> We have that $\int_{C_N} |f|$ is bounded and $\int_{B_0} f = \lim_{N \to \infty} \int_{C_N} |f| = 4(\sqrt{2} - 1) $.